# Reason behind different derivative notation depending on the number of independent variables

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation

In the freely available Georgia University course on linear algebra by Theodore Shifrin, and [at this point](https://youtu.be/1GX3NnqNjjQ?t=12m42s), he mentions that for single independent variable functions, he uses prime notation $(')$, as opposed to for multivariable derivatives, for which he reserves a $(D)$ notation.

In the following function composition,

$$
\mathbb R \overset{\vec g}{\to}\mathbb R^3 \overset{ f}{\to}\mathbb R
$$

$$\left ( f\circ \vec g \right )\color{red}{'}(t) = \color{red}{D}f\left(\vec g(t)\right)\,\vec g\color{red}{'}(t)$$

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation) the $(D)$ notation for differentiation seems to correspond to the Euler's, while the apostrophe would be Lagrange's. So, given these historical connotations, is there any universality to Professor Shifrin's notation, and if so, is there any rational to it?

Comment: No, no universality. Some use $'$ for both. Some use $d$ for one and $'$ for the other, etc. Also that should be $Df(g(t))$ not $D(f(g(t)))$

Comment: @TedShifrin might care to see the question...

Comment: I do it for clarity and to make the reader (student) think about what domains are. $\vec f$ is used when the function is *vector*-valued; $f$ is used when the function is *scalar*-valued.